# Virtualbox Only Allows 32bit VMs on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

I want to create a VM on my 64-bit Ubuntu 20.10 build to test out Arch Linux (and namely to see whether or not I can manage to install it without breaking things). To that end I installed Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.16 via a .deb file from Oracle's own website (20.10 didn't have an explicitly compatible version so I downloaded the build for 20.04 LTS). When I open it and try to create a new VM, I'm only offered 32-bit options:

[Virtualbox only shows me 32-bit options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j48aa.png)

The SHA256 sums match with the ones on the official website (can link if asked). I do not know what else to troubleshoot, as all other incidences I have seen of this issue seem to have occurred on Windows.

How can I make Virtualbox give me 64bit options for the VM?

Comment: Do you have images of the drop down menu? Press the Arch Linux 32 bit option

Comment: I am sorry that I am nowhere near my notes. If nobody gives you a solid answer, I'm pretty sure I've seen this before. Check in your BIOS settings and make sure that virtualization is enabled. If it's Intel, there should be two of them. One is called VT-d, as memory serves. Make sure that they're both enabled.

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne I don't have a screenshot (I tried with PrtSc), but I have Shutter installed and I can try with that as well. All distro options given in the drop-down menu are 32-bit, if that helps.

Comment: @ygtozc You should try installing Virtualbox from the distro repos

Comment: `sudo apt install virtualbox` should work

Comment: unless you need the website packages for some purpose

Comment: @KGIII You got it right! Under Security -> Virtualization, there were two disabled options regarding VMs. (One was called Intel Virtualization or something, and the other was VT-d or TV-d.) After enabling them and restarting, I was able to create a 64-bit Arch Linux VM. Since I plan on using it to practice installing Arch, I did not tinker with it further, but I got as far as being asked to pick a boot media without any apparent problems! Thank you. You can write it as an answer and I'll mark the question as solved.

Comment: also first uninstall the package from the website if you are following my answer to prevent conflicts

Comment: yes virtualisation is quite important

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne I don't recall where exactly I saw it but apparently downloading it straight from repos is not recommended due to those versions being old. I don't mind downloading and installing a .deb file at all anyhow, so it worked out, I think. Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you don't have one, or both, of the virtualization options enabled in your BIOS.

Reboot your computer and enter the setup pages. It will vary based on OEM, but it's often F2. Once you're in there, it is also going to vary. You'll be looking for two options that look similar to:

**Intel Virtualization Technology** and **Intel VT-d Feature**

Make sure both are enabled and make sure you save the settings before rebooting your computer. You'll need to check carefully, as this too will vary per OEM and models.